# How to set PYTHONPATH in Senzing 33 for running G2Explorer

Tags: python

Senzing is entity resolution platform.
We have upgraded to 3.3 from 2.8. Now when I am trying to run G2Explorer.py it is giving error .

Please export PYTHONPATH=

PYTHONPATH is set to /opt/senzing/g2/python:/home/pidtwsp/medsentry/python/senzing:/opt/senzing/g2/python:/home/pidtwsp/medsentry/python

Using export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:${SENZING_ROOT}/python/senzing:${PYTHONPATH}:${SENZING_ROOT}/python
Also sourced the setupEnv.

Still I am getting this error. Can someone through light on this ?